# Вывод видео в окне Windows базовыми средствами WinAPI

Tags: winapi, видео

Есть всякие библиотеки и фреймворки для работы с видео, но, например, при их статической линковке они требуют кучу зависимостей, среди которых библиотека `GDI+`, возможно `COM`, и прочие стандартные средства WinAPI.

**Так какой же базовый алгоритм вывода видео в Windows? Это покадровая перерисовка окна битмапами, полученными при декодировании видеопотока, или что-то ещё, о чём я не знаю?**

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться ActiveX плеером (Windows media pleayer можно найти примеры [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), либо [MCI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Win).

Comment: Ну да, это уже готовые интерфейсы. Мне же интересно как оно устроенно внутри. Чтобы например, наложить текст на видео с определённым форматированием через GDI. Я так понимаю тут нужна покадровая обработка

Comment: Насколько я проникся видео-кодированием, то нужно не забывать, что полный кадр, 1024x768x25x3=56 Мбайт/сек (500 мегабит) мощность потока.  Т.е. за 1 секунду нужно "разпаковать" такое колличество информации - это и есть основная проблема. Для решения этой проблемы используется не полный вывод, а частичный (есть полные кадры, а есть инкрементальные). Из низкоуровневых user-WinAPI назову такие:  MaskBlt (показывает частично изображение), DrawIconEx (показывает полные кадры). Но когда понадобилось прорисовать карту, то OpenGL оказалось что работает гораздо быстрее. GDI не копал.

Comment: ОК, немного раскрою карты... В приложении используется OpenCV для различных задач для работы с веб-камерой. Когда стал вопрос о проигрывании видео в приложении (уже не камеры, а файла), дабы не раздувать исполняемый файл было решено использовать cv и для вывода видео. Делаю `cvCreateFileCapture()`, получаю `iplimage`, перевожу в `HBITMAP` чтобы добавить русский текст, потом опять в `iplimage` и `cvShowImage()`. Проблема в том, что `cvNamedWindow` для вывода никак не принимает необходимый стиль `WS_EX_TOPMOST`, поэтому хочу сделать обычное окно с этим стилем и выводить в него. Только как?...

Comment: Может вам для текста лучше использовать окно, обвёрнутое в [регион](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), а регион формировать для каждой строки текста свой. Регион не даст "зарисовать" ту область которая отмечена как сплошная (окно кастомной формы) и обновит только нужный кусок окна. При этом проверок делать не нужно

Comment: DicectX с вашей задачей хорошо справится, но нужно долго изучать библиотеку. В KM-плеере по-моему это сделано через него.

Comment: Задайте отдельно вопрос "как на видео наложить текст" или что-то в этом роде. Я вам тогда скину пример наложения через region. Возможно и другие учасники дадут свои примеры. (если это ещё нужно)